# Nginx Reverse proxy - top-level domain not working - DNS error

Tags: nginx, dns, reverse-proxy, devops

I am trying to setup an nginx reverse proxy for my domain and a few of its subdomains. The subdomains work perfectly, but I keep getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on the top-level domain.

[image]

Except for the `server_name` and the `proxy_pass` port, the nginx config is identical between the top-level domain and its subdomains.

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

DNS settings:

[image]

This is more likely to be a DNS issue than an Nginx one, but I don't understand why the subdomains work and the top-level one doesn't.

Comment: Definitely not nginx's problem. Check if commandline tools (like `ping` or `host`) resolve your domain correctly. Try to restart browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexeyTen's comment about restarting my browser gave me an idea which ended up fixing my issue.

Basically, I use [Acrylic DNS proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) on my development computer to handle `.local` domains for development. Most people normally use the `hosts` file for adding local domains, but I find that process tedious as I have worked with hundreds of local domains over the years so I ended up using this proxy that accepts wildcard domains which means I never have to touch the hosts file again.

However, in this instance, my local DNS proxy seemed to have a corrupt cache of my top-level domain. I just purged the cache and restarted the proxy and that fixed everything. I don't exactly know why this happened, but it's good to know that it can happen so it would be the first place for me to look if something similar happens in the future.

Thank you to @AlexeyTen for making me think outside the box. While it wasn't the browser's DNS cache, that comment made me realize that perhaps there was nothing wrong with my DNS settings on the server and instead something wrong with my local computer.